# Output limit exceeded in c++ class

Tags: class, data-structures, c++14

[enter link description here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/j9e20Rv8eP)
Please check in this code if i am using both push and pop together it is giving output limit exceeded error.
I have created a class Stack and within the down function i created a pointer to the stack.

Comment: Please add your code to the question. A link might go dead in the future leaving this question useless to anyone else. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized the pointer in the below line in your code.

```
void Stack::down()
{
    Stack *s1;
    //.....
}
```

The behavior of this statement execution is undefined.

On Windows this statement execution throws a run-time exception. But on other platforms the program may behave differently. The IDE on the website may be running this program on a different platform and that platform may be running some piece of code infinitely due to improper value in top member variable. Hence the output buffer is exceeding its capacity.

In my opinion, below loop is running infinitely.

```
while(!(s1->isEmpty()))
{
    int temp=s1->pop();
    push(temp);
   printf("\n%d\t",temp);
}
```

Initialize this pointer and your program runs fine.